# visual studio 2015 web api - no web api template

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I installed vs 2015 community, for the sake of practice with web api.
I opened the shortcut called 'Blend for visual studio 2015', and open
a new project.
I don't see anything related to web.
I click on file->new -> website and see no options.
Everything is empty , no web templates.
I downloaded 'microsoft asp.net and web tools' - 
https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c94a02e9-f2e9-4bad-a952-a63a967e3935
I opened again the VS and see no change.
Any idea ?
Thanks !

Answer (score 6):

Instead of opening 'Blend for visual studio 2015', look for 'Visual Studio 2015' in start menu.

Blend for Visual Studio (formerly Microsoft Expression Blend) is a user interface design tool developed for creating graphical interfaces for web and desktop applications that blend the features of these two types of applications - WPF and Silverlight.

Once you open VS2015, Click on New Project > Select Web from templates > then select ASP.NET web application like shown below-

[image: New Project]

Once you click OK and move to next screen, you will get option to select WebApi like this-

[image: WebApi]

If you are looking for ASP.NET-core web api, then you should install .NET core SDK and preview toolkit from this [link](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#windows)

See if this helps.